# Problemas para crear usuario en oracle error ORA-65096

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

hace unas semanas atrás logre crear un usuario pero hoy al tratar de realizarlo no me permite, estoy conectado de la conexión system y nada, al principio ocupaba la primera linea de codigo y funcionaba, ahora ya no me funciona y los servicios se encuentran inicializados.

```
alter session set “_ORACLE_SCRIPT”=true;

CREATE USER pc2 IDENTIFIED BY pc2
DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
grant connect, resource, create view, create materialized view to pc2;
```

Me presenta el siguiente error

```
Error SQL: ORA-65096: nombre de usuario o rol común no válido
65096. 00000 -  "invalid common user or role name"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create a common user or role with a name
           that was not valid for common users or roles.  In addition to
           the usual rules for user and role names, common user and role
           names must start with C## or c## and consist only of ASCII
           characters.
*Action:   Specify a valid common user or role name.
```

Comment: ¿cuál de las dos sentencias es la que te presenta el error?

Comment: @jachguate al crear usuario, porque después logre entender y como antes ocupaba Oracle 11G creaba el usuario normal, pero ahora con Oracle 12c no se porque al crear un usuario hay que poner c##nombreusuario para que te deje crearlo sin problemas y no ocupar la primera linea que puse arriba de alter sessión.

Comment: La respuesta debe ir en el campo respuesta!!!!

Comment: Esa no es la respuesta, @gbianchi

Comment: @Alfabravo aunque no sea la respuesta (nunca dije que lo fuera), fue para aclararle a Op que la respuesta va en el campo respuesta!

Comment: @Alfabravo Op edito su pregunta y lo puso ahi...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, tienes que poner la versión de Oracle en tu pregunta.

El error se debe a que, desde Oracle 12c, hay un modo de instalación en el que se crea un CDB (un contenedor) y múltiples PDB (pluggable DB). Los usuarios de contenedor (del CDB) deben tener la estructura que citas en el comentario (c##xxxxx, con sólo caracteres ASCII) y estos usuarios **NO** se usan para crear bases de datos que uses en tu aplicación. Son para gestionar el contenedor, las características de funcionamiento de la BD, redo logs, parámetros de arranque, etc.

Para crear un usuario en cuyo esquema vayas a crear tablas y demás como normalmente lo hacías, conéctate a la PDB (por defecto es al **serviceName** `orclpdb`, no confundir con el SID `orcl` que es el de la CDB) y crea tu usuario normalmente.

Te recomiendo acudir a la documentación para entender mejor los cambios, pues se ve además que pasaste de una versión a otra suponiendo que eran iguales.

Comment: la forma mas simple de acceder al pdbs es darle un `show pdbs;` y luego un `alter session set container="pdb_name";` y ya podras crear los usuarios.

Answer (score 3):

la solucion es
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
antes del codigo y listo
exito ami me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Excelentes comentarios de todos los colaboradores. Hoy 2022 me ha funcionado conectarme al servicio.

Citando:
ara crear un usuario en cuyo esquema vayas a crear tablas y demás como normalmente lo hacías, conéctate a la PDB (por defecto es al serviceName orclpdb, no confundir con el SID orcl que es el de la CDB) y crea tu usuario normalmente.